# Auto deletion of documents from mongodb after specified time

Tags: mongodb

I want to auto delete documents from a `collection` in mongodb based on a `ttl`. I have gone through other answers and figured out the following way:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

This will delete the documents after `expireAfterSeconds` interval from `createdAt` field.

However, the problem with above is that it is not document specific. In the above scenario, all documents will be deleted after `3600` time from creation. However, in my case, each document in the collection needs to be deleted at different time intervals. So, each document need to have its own `ttl`. How can I achieve this?