# Refresh Tokens in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jwt, token

What is the best solution to remove a refresh token from MongoDB automatically.

On login the user is given a temporary auth token which lasts 30 seconds. They are also given a permanent token, stored in MongoDB, which currently lasts until they log out.

I want to remove the permanent one at the end of every day, but I'm not sure how to do that without having a cron job running (to monitor what time it is). This seems a bit complex for such a small task. Is there a way mongo would know what the time is and then remove the refresh token?

This is how the token collection looks:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To auto-delete the MongoDB documents after some time, you should use the TTL(time to live) collection feature documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416335/auto-deletion-of-documents-from-mongodb-after-specified-time).

Essentially, you need to create an index on the collection that stores the token documents. For your use case, you can do something like this:

```
// This would delete the tokens document after 3600seconds after creation
// You can tweak the time as you wish. 
db.tokens.createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**NodeJS, mongodb.**
Just simply create a model for each token.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const tokenSchema = new Schema({
    _userId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'user'
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    expireAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      index: { expires: 60*60*24 }
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('tokens', tokenSchema)
```